# how to hide work profile id from playstore in EMM

Tags: android-management-api, emm, android-work-profile

I have been working with google Enterprise android management api i have successfully implemented QR code Enrollment of my android device but the problem is that i'm unable to hide the work profile id from play store how may i suppose to do it.

I have tried every this from policy controll but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to hide the Work Profile Account from being displayed in the Play Store through the Android Management API. It's important to note that the Work Profile Account is a unique identifier associated with the Work Profile and is not intended to be concealed within the Work Profile environment.

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.

Comment: but I have seen few vendors doing though then how they are able to pull of this thing

Comment: In the [Google Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/getstarted), the [Users object](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/users#resource-representations) includes a set of parameters, including the `displayName` field, which allows customization of the Work Profile Account name displayed in the Play Store. This field could be used to replace the default Work Profile Account name. However, this customization behavior is no longer supported in the new user interface of the Play Store.

Comment: no worry buddy I found the solution